# Error: Cannot find module '/app/react-web/react-scripts'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i have these 2 start scripts:

package.json in root directory

```
    "start": "cd react-web && npm run postinstall && export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=gianlucaherokutest320880 && npm start"
```

and package.json in react-web

```
    "start": "node react-scripts --max_old_space_size=2560 start",
```

when i run this, it gives me the error:

```
    2021-04-20T04:23:34.164924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:34.496420+00:00 app[web.1]: added 1 package from 6 contributors and audited 486 packages in 11.821s
2021-04-20T04:23:35.248259+00:00 app[web.1]: found 56017 vulnerabilities (40514 low, 15 moderate, 15488 high)
2021-04-20T04:23:35.248272+00:00 app[web.1]: run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2021-04-20T04:23:35.265102+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/shared -> /app/shared
2021-04-20T04:23:35.273265+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/react-web/node_modules/shared -> /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/shared -> /app/shared
2021-04-20T04:23:35.703189+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:35.703198+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-web@0.1.0 start /app/react-web
2021-04-20T04:23:35.703199+00:00 app[web.1]: > node --max_old_space_size=4096 react-scripts start
2021-04-20T04:23:35.703199+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832305+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832306+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832307+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832308+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/react-web/react-scripts'
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832309+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832309+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832310+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832311+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832311+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832312+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: []
2021-04-20T04:23:35.832312+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-04-20T04:23:35.844563+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-20T04:23:35.845023+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-20T04:23:35.853896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! react-web@0.1.0 start: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 react-scripts start`
2021-04-20T04:23:35.854062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-20T04:23:35.854278+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-20T04:23:35.854426+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the react-web@0.1.0 start script.
2021-04-20T04:23:35.854570+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-20T04:23:35.860177+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:35.860333+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-20T04:23:35.860386+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-20T04_23_35_855Z-debug.log
2021-04-20T04:23:35.881653+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-20T04:23:35.882017+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-20T04:23:35.891329+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cleaning-assistant@1.0.0 start: `cd react-web && npm run postinstall && export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=gianlucaherokutest320880 && npm start`
2021-04-20T04:23:35.891459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-20T04:23:35.891617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-20T04:23:35.891717+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the cleaning-assistant@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-20T04:23:35.891818+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-20T04:23:35.898578+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-20T04:23:35.898782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-20T04:23:35.898874+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-20T04_23_35_892Z-debug.log
2021-04-20T04:23:35.981329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

but the weird thing is, i have react-scripts installed. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the complete error log? seems like you are referring this `'/app/react-web/react-scripts'` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Ravikumar just edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

check whether node_modules folder and Package-lock.json file exist or not,

if exist, Delete Node_modules and Package-lock.json

and run the below command

```
npm install
```

and do

```
npm start
```